# karatsuba algorithm implementation in python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, karatsuba

Below is my python implementation for the Karatsuba multiplication algorithm. This code seems to work for most inputs, but starts failing after the digits grow too large. For example, with the 64 digit inputs 
`x = 3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592`
`y = 2718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627`
the algorithm fails. But when I use only the first 35 digits, the algorithm works. Can anyone explain where this implementation is falling short?

```
from math import floor, ceil
def karatsuba(x, y):
  sx = str(x)
  sy = str(y)
  n = max(len(sx), len(sy))
  if len(sx) == 1 and len(sy) == 1:
    return x*y
  m = ceil(n/2)
  a = int(x / (10**m))
  b = int(x % (10**m))
  c = int(y / (10**m))
  d = int(y % (10**m))
  ac = karatsuba(int(a), int(c))
  bd = karatsuba(int(b), int(d))
  adbc = karatsuba(int(a) + int(b), int(c) + int(d)) - ac - bd
  return int(str(ac) + '0' * 2 * m) + int(str(adbc) + '0' * m) + bd
```

Comment: (While marvelling at your confidence in the accuracy of Python floating point arithmetic accuracy, let me suggest considering a) integer arithmetic (not necessarily "thinking base ten") b) manipulating decimal representations for split just as you do for splice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = int(x / (10**m))
c = int(y / (10**m))
```

These two lines are prone to rounding errors. In python3, the `/` operator is a floating-point division operator. Just change `/` to `//` for integer division.

Try this code to see the problem

```
x = 2222222222222222222222222222222222
p = 10**17
print(int(x/p))
print(int(x//p))
```

Comment: I included an example in my answer